# Оптимизация повторяющегося кода в методе

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, c#-7.0

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно оформить повторяющийся код вызова диалогового окна в методе ButFurther_Click(вызывается после нажатия кнопки в WindowsForms)? Я пытался оформить в метод внутри метода ButFurther_Click, но это не работает.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Anomalies
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //private string openPath;
        
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void ButFurther_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string pathFarther = @"C:\Python";
            
            if (Directory.Exists(pathFarther)) 
            {
                if (File.Exists(pathFarther + @"\python.exe"))
                {
                    string path = pathFarther + @"\python.exe";
                    // запуск распознавания аномалий
                    string fileName = "python\\open_window.py";
                    if (File.Exists(fileName))
                    {
                        Process p = new Process();
                        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path, fileName)  
                        {
                            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                            UseShellExecute = false,
                            CreateNoWindow = true
                        };
                        p.Start();

                        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                        p.WaitForExit();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Не найден файл open_window.py");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Выберите другой каталог, куда установлен Python или установите его");
                    SetPath();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Выберите каталог, куда установлен Python или установите его");
                SetPath();
            }

            string SetPath()
            {
                FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
                DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();
                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string path = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;
                    MessageBox.Show(path);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Оформил в метод SetPath(), но VS 2019 пишет "не все пути к коду возвращают значение".

Comment: Где ваши попытки и что конкретно не работает?

Comment: Почему ваша кнопка ответственна за логику запуска процесса, вывода сообщения и так далее? Это нарушение единой ответственности из SOLID. Разбейте все на методы, отдельные кусочки, которые отвечают за что-то свое, а затем вызывайте их там, где надо, тем самым вы уберете дублирование и код станет в разы чище и приятней.

Comment: С C# плохо знаком. К кнопке привязал запуск процесса, описанный в питоновском файле.  Повторяющийся код оформил в метод, но VS ругается на пути.

Comment: `К кнопке привязал запуск процесса` - нет, у вас кнопка выполняет ряд инструкций, которые тесно связаны друг с другом. Она запускает процесс, она формирует путь, выводит сообщение, проверяет и так далее. А должна лишь вызвать метод, например `StartScript("path/script.py");`, все, вот это у вас должно быть только внутри события кнопки. В методе `StartScript()` вы проверяете например пути и вызываете другой метод, который стартанет вам процесс. Ну и так далее, по цепочке, где каждый метод - это своя отдельная логика выполнения чего-то, то есть, метод с единственной ответственностью.